# Qt - Drag and Drop - Custom Graphic Scene - Event error

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview

I created simple d&d drop - soemthing like QT Creator menu - ListView on the side and DragScene (my own subclass of QGraphicsScene). I want to created new Graphic item ( i already got my custo mclasses for it) to be added there - in place where i dropped it. I created my own class:

DragScene.h

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMimeData>

#include "CustomObj.h"

class DragScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    DragScene(QObject* parent = 0);

 protected:
     void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
};
```

DragScene.cpp

```
#include "DragScene.h"

DragScene::DragScene(QObject* parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
}

void DragScene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
}

void DragScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
}

void DragScene::dragLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
}

void DragScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
        CustomObj* newObject = new CustomObj(0,0,50,50);
  //      newObject->setPos(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y()); //(1)
        this->addItem(newObject);

        qDebug() <<"New object";
}
```

Now I jsut can't set those parameters. Everytime i try to use event (like in (1) ) in those functions I get errors:

> invalid use of incomplete type 'class QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent'
>            newObject->setPos(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
>                                   ^
>
> forward declaration of 'class QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent'  class
>   QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent;
>          ^
>
> invalid use of incomplete type 'class QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent'
>            newObject->setPos(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
>                                                     ^
>
> forward declaration of 'class QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent'  class
>   QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent;
>          ^

I have no idea why anymore - i saw few exemples and those wre useing event without any trouble, like:
[Qt - drag and drop with graphics view framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732343/qt-drag-and-drop-with-graphics-view-framework)

EDIT 1:
Adding:

```
#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
```

recolved it, but now I can see my event isnt passing any position - every object is stted to (0,0).

Comment: Your initial problem is solved (I voted to close it as it is a simple header forgotten). Please don't update your question to change its purpose. Instead open a new question including only material relevant to the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
```

Comment: Thx, that resolved it. I feel silly about it now. But why is that? Examples from QT's page didnt containt it (ew. Label: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-draganddrop-draggabletext-example.html )

Comment: @Arker If you are referring to the `QDropEvent` used byt the example, the example includes `QtGui` which pretty much includes everything GUI releated. But you shouldn't do that.

Comment: That example doesn't deal with the *QGraphicsScene*, so it doesn't need that class to be included.